# Debugging after reactivating an activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

Is it possible to continue debugging in Eclipse after activity is destroyed due to system constraints and then again recreated, but another application is used on device in the meantime.

So, for example:
I start debugging, do something in app, then press home button and onSaveInstanceState is called. If I hold home button I will have my app there, if I press the icon, app will continue and debugging will work. But, if I enter into another app after exiting from mine, debugging will not work anymore. (I'm doing that to dry up memory sources so when I continue using my app activity will be reactivated and onRestoreInstanceState will be called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when activity is destroyed then all the memory and other resources will be revoked from the activity. so u cannot resume the debugging then.